# No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm new to this android programming. So, now I have a problem when I want to go from one activity to another. When I run in an emulator it displays MyDemo has stopped working after press the button to direct to another page. I have read and tried few solutions posted in similar question but can't seem to solve the problem. Any suggestions would be a great help to me. Thank you.

This is the error log:

> 09-09 10:56:36.046    2474-2489/com.example.dothis.demo D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ >Render dirty regions requested: true
>   09-09 10:56:36.057    2474-2474/com.example.dothis.demo D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae0d8d40, tid 2474
>   09-09 10:56:36.070    2474-2474/com.example.dothis.demo D/Atlas﹕ >Validating map...
>   09-09 10:56:36.191    2474-2489/com.example.dothis.demo D/﹕ >HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae0d8e50, tid 2489
>   09-09 10:56:36.205    2474-2489/com.example.dothis.demo I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ >Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   09-09 10:56:36.220    2474-2489/com.example.dothis.demo D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ >Enabling debug mode 0
>   0>9-09 10:56:36.241    2474-2489/com.example.dothis.demo W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>   09-09 10:56:36.241    2474-2489/com.example.dothis.demo W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ >Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c25680, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>   09-09 10:56:40.067    2474-2474/com.example.dothis.demo D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >Shutting down VM
>   09-09 10:56:40.067    2474-2474/com.example.dothis.demo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ >FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>      Process: com.example.dothis.demo, PID: 2474
>     android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle >Intent { act=AnotherActivity }
>              at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1765)
>              at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
>              at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3736)
>              at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3697)
>              at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4007)
>              at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3975)
>              at com.example.dothis.demo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:18)
>              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
>             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
>              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java>:899)
>              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>   09-09 10:56:42.512    2474-2474/com.example.dothis.demo I/Process﹕ Sending >signal. PID: 2474 SIG: 9

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.dothis.demo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OnClickListener listnr=new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i= new Intent("AnotherActivity");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
    Button btn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(listnr);
}
}
```

Another activity:

```
package com.example.dothis.demo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dothis.demo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
<android:uses-permission          android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<android:uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"    />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AnotherActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.AnotherActivity"   />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your action needs to be a fully qualified name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.dothis.demo.AnotherActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

The other option is to not use an action to start your other activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: cannot use `this` in inner class, otherwise correct.

Comment: @poss There is a way actually. `MainActivity.this`

Comment: thank you so much @ColinGillespie...The second one worked..i can now run the two actvities.